# C++ passing in a * to a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, parameter-passing, dereference

I am attempting to retrieve an item from a chained array hash table.  The retrieve function belongs to the a class table, of which the hash tables are members.  The table is a member of the client class.  It is for a class, so we are extremely limited in what we can use (eg.. no strings, only arrays of characters).  I want to pass in an array of items from the client and the name of the item or characteristic of the item I want to generate a hash key from.

...
part of main that calls the retrieve function (the int passed in is a flag that determines weather I am searching by name or by effect)

```
    program.reference.retrieve("Abecean Longfin", program.client_item, 1);

    cout << program.client_list[0].name;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

....

item.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int ASIZE = 30;
const int SIZE = 92;
const int HNSIZE = 41;
const int HESIZE = 17;

struct item
{
    item();
    ~item();
    char * name;
    char * effect1;
    char * effect2;
    char * effect3;
    char * effect4;
    int count;
    //int keygen(int,int);
    /*int name_key;
    int ef1_key;
    int ef2_key;
    int ef3_key;
    int ef4_key;*/
};
```

....
retrieve function

```
int table::retrieve(char item_in[],item*item_list, int name_flag)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(name_flag)
    {
        node * temp;
        int key = keygen(item_in,HNSIZE);
        if(!(name_table.ht[key]))
        return 0;
        else
        temp = name_table.ht[key];
        while(temp)
        {
            if(!strcmp(item_in,temp->ingredient->name))
            item_list[i] = *temp->ingredient;
            ++i;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        node * temp;
        int key = keygen(item_in,HESIZE);
        if(!(ef1_table.ht[key]) && !(ef2_table.ht[key]) && !(ef3_table.ht[key]) && !(ef4_table.ht[key]))
        return 0;
        else
        {
            temp = ef1_table.ht[key];
            while(temp)
            {
                if(!strcmp(item_in,temp->ingredient->effect1))
                item_list[i] = *temp->ingredient;
                ++i;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp = ef2_table.ht[key];
            while(temp)
            {
                if(!strcmp(item_in,temp->ingredient->effect2))
                item_list[i] = *temp->ingredient;
                ++i;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp = ef3_table.ht[key];
            while(temp)
            {
                if(!strcmp(item_in,temp->ingredient->effect3))
                item_list[i] = *temp->ingredient;
                ++i;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp = ef4_table.ht[key];
            while(temp)
            {
                if(!strcmp(item_in,temp->ingredient->effect4))
                item_list[i] = *temp->ingredient;
                ++i;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

....

client.h

```
#include "table.h"

struct client
{
    client();
    int fill_list(int,int,int);
    int copy(char*,char*,int);
    int display(char*, int, item*);
    item * client_list;
    table reference;
    table inventory;
    item client_item;
};
```

....

table.h

```
#include "hash.h"

class table
{
public:
    table();
    ~table();
    int fill(item*);
    int insert(item&, nHash&);
    int insert(item&, eHash&, int);
    int retrieve(char*,item*,int);
    int remove(int,item&);
    int remove(int);
    int check_hash(int,int,int);
    int keygen(char*, int);
    int from_list(int, item&);
    int into_list(int, item&);
    item* get_list();

private:
    item * item_list;
    nHash name_table;
    eHash ef1_table;
    eHash ef2_table;
    eHash ef3_table;
    eHash ef4_table;
};
```

....

the keygen function

```
int table::keygen(char*input, int hash_size)
{
    if(input)
    {
        int key = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(input[i])
        {
            key = key + input[i] * 101 * input[i++];
        }

        return key%hash_size;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

....
Added the client_item init

```
client::client()
{
    client_item.name = new char[ASIZE];
    client_item.effect1 = new char[ASIZE];
    client_item.effect2 = new char[ASIZE];
    client_item.effect3 = new char[ASIZE];
    client_item.effect4 = new char[ASIZE];
    client_list = NULL;
}
```

I'm sure there are other things I need to include.  But, I figure this would get things rolling.  I'm still really new to programming and C++.

The problem I am having is dereferencing a NULL pointer when I try to cout the name.  At least I assume that's what "Access violation reading location 0x00000000" is.

Comment: Create a new project, copy everything, and start removing things while keeping the access violation error in order to provide a minimum reproducible test case. There is way too much code in your question. Unfortunately the place where you initializate `program.client_item` is not there.

Comment: Will do.  Sorry still new to this site as well as everything else. thanks

Comment: You need a short, self-contained, correct (compilable) example; this is none of these. See <sscce.org>.

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger. When running in the debugger, it will stop at the error, showing you the location of it, and also let you examine variables to see which one contains the faulty value. Then use the call stack to see when and where the variable gets the faulty value.

Comment: In the provided code
client_list = NULL
And it is never initialized, check in your code if you actually initialize it. put a breakpoint on the "cout" line and the nyou can see values in the watch or step into functions to see where the problem is. Find the problem.. then post a more specific question maybe